# Correct way to use multiple conditions in If statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, enums

In my code I want to check if the status of a Dog `object` **is not** that of 3 `Enums`:

```
if((dogList.get(i).getStatus()!= dogStatus.SLEEPING 
   || dogList.get(i).getStatus()!= dogStatus.WALKING
   ||dogList.get(i).getStatus()!= dogStatus.EATING  )){

//do something 

}
```

Is this the correct way to combine the 3 `||` conditions? I ask as my program is not behaving as I expect.

Comment: it's "proper", but it's not correct. you're testing for inequality. since getStatus() can only ever have one value, you'll always evaluate as TRUE,b ecause the other two statements cannot be equal. you want `&&` instead. consider this equivalent: if this cat is not a dog and this cat is not a gorilla and this cat is not a cat. v.s. the equivalent with `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: You would want to use `&&` (AND) instead of `||` (OR) for this. For example if the status was WALKING your if would read `TRUE || FALSE || TRUE = TRUE` when `TRUE && FALSE && TRUE = FALSE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
if (status != SLEEPING && status != WALKING...)
```

Note the '&&', since you want to check it's not `WALKING` *and* it's not `SLEEPING` *and* so on

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is that you should use `&&` not `||`, as explained well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36184338/3973077). However, since you are using an `enum`, you can tidy this up by using `switch`.

```
switch (dogList.get(i).getStatus()) {
    case SLEEPING:case EATING:case WALKING:
        break;
    default:
        // write your code here.
}
```

(Technically this is not exactly the same as your (corrected) version as that executes the code if the result is `null`, whereas `switch` throws a `NullPointerException`).

Comment: Whilst it's a valid alternative I'm not sure this *answers* the above question directly...